# SAPUI5 custom control getAggregation() is null

Tags: gridview, sapui5

I have written a custom control in sapui5. Its a virtual keyboard (onscreen keyboard) having a MatrixLayout and a lot of buttons as aggregations. I added a "public" function to the control which should allow me to disable some of the buttons. But when I am trying to access it within this function all my aggregations except my MatrixLayout-Aggregation is null.

Can somebody help me out how I can access my aggregations (buttons)?
I have tried it with visibility hidden and public. I do see the generated accessors then, but those return "null" too.
If I try to get the aggregation "_layout" my MatrixLayout is returned.

I am trying to access it this way:

```
    onVirtualKeyboardClickBase : function(oEvent, oController){

    var virtualKeyboard = oEvent.getSource().disableButton("_btnMinus");
    }
```

This is the code of the custom control:

```
   (function () {
    "use strict";

    jQuery.sap.declare("de.vw.timerec.controls.VirtualKeyboard");

    $.sap.includeStyleSheet("css/VirtualKeyboard.css");

    jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.commons.Button");

    sap.ui.core.Control.extend("de.vw.timerec.controls.VirtualKeyboard", {

        // the control API:
        metadata : {
            properties : {
                /* Business Object properties */
                "title"           : {type : "string"},
                "width"           : {type: "sap.ui.core.CSSSize", defaultValue: "253px" },
                "buttonWidth"     : {type: "sap.ui.core.CSSSize", defaultValue: "57px" },
                "buttonHeight"    : {type: "sap.ui.core.CSSSize", defaultValue: "57px" }
            },

            aggregations : {
                "_layout"    : {type : "sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btn1"      : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btn2"      : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btn3"      : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btnDel"    : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btn4"      : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btn5"      : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btn6"      : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btnAlpha"  : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btn7"      : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btn8"      : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btn9"      : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btnBack"   : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btn0"      : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btnComma"  : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"},
                "_btnMinus"  : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "public"},
                "_btnNext"   : {type : "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple : false, visibility: "hidden"}
            },

            associations: { },

            events : { 
                click : {enablePreventDefault : true}
            }
        },


        init : function() {

            var oControl = this;
            var oMatrixLayout;
            var oBtn1, oBtn2, oBtn3, oBtnDel, oBtn4, oBtn5, oBtn6, oBtnAlpha, 
            oBtn7, oBtn8, oBtn9, oBtnBack, oBtn0, oBtnComma, oBtnMinus, oBtnNext;

            oMatrixLayout = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({
                id : this.getId() + "-matrixLayout",
                layoutFixed : true, 
                columns : 4,
                width : "100%"
            });
            this.setAggregation("_layout", oMatrixLayout);

            oBtn1 = this._createButton("1", "1", oControl, true);
            this.setAggregation("_btn1", oBtn1);

            oBtn2 = this._createButton("2", "2", oControl, true);
            this.setAggregation("_btn2", oBtn2);

            oBtn3 = this._createButton("3", "3", oControl, true);
            this.setAggregation("_btn3", oBtn3);

            oBtnDel = this._createButton("", "delete", oControl, false);
            oBtnDel.setIcon("sap-icon://undo");
            this.setAggregation("_btnDel", oBtnDel);
            oMatrixLayout.createRow(oBtn1, oBtn2, oBtn3, oBtnDel);

            oBtn4 = this._createButton("4", "4", oControl, true);
            this.setAggregation("_btn4", oBtn4);

            oBtn5 = this._createButton("5", "5", oControl, true);
            this.setAggregation("_btn5", oBtn5);

            oBtn6 = this._createButton("6", "6", oControl, true);
            this.setAggregation("_btn6", oBtn6);

            oBtnAlpha = this._createButton("Alpha", "alpha", oControl, false);
            this.setAggregation("_btnAlpha", oBtnAlpha);
            oMatrixLayout.createRow(oBtn4, oBtn5, oBtn6, oBtnAlpha);

            oBtn7 = this._createButton("7", "7", oControl, true);
            this.setAggregation("_btn7", oBtn7);

            oBtn8 = this._createButton("8", "8", oControl, true);
            this.setAggregation("_btn8", oBtn8);

            oBtn9 = this._createButton("9", "9", oControl, true);
            this.setAggregation("_btn9", oBtn9);

            oBtnBack = this._createButton("", "back", oControl, false);
            oBtnBack.setIcon("sap-icon://arrow-top");
            this.setAggregation("_btnBack", oBtnBack);
            oMatrixLayout.createRow(oBtn7, oBtn8, oBtn9, oBtnBack);

            oBtn0 = this._createButton("0", "0", oControl, true);
            this.setAggregation("_btn0", oBtn0);

            oBtnComma = this._createButton(",", ",", oControl, true);
            this.setAggregation("_btnComma", oBtnComma);

            oBtnMinus = this._createButton("-", "-", oControl, true);
            this.setAggregation("_btnMinus", oBtnMinus);

            oBtnNext = this._createButton("", "next", oControl, false);
            oBtnNext.setIcon("sap-icon://arrow-bottom");
            this.setAggregation("_btnNext", oBtnNext);
            oMatrixLayout.createRow(oBtn0, oBtnComma, oBtnMinus, oBtnNext);
        },

        onAfterRendering: function () {

        },

        _createButton : function (text, buttonValue, oControl, isDigitButton) { 

            var styleClassName = "virtualKeyboardButtonDigit";
            if (!isDigitButton) styleClassName = "virtualKeyboardButtonSpecial";

            var buttonIdHelper = buttonValue;
            if (buttonValue == ",") {
                buttonIdHelper = "comma";
            }

            if (buttonValue == "-") {
                buttonIdHelper = "minus";
            }

            var buttonId = this.getId() + "virtualKeyboardButton_" + buttonIdHelper;
            var oBtn   = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                id: buttonId,
                text: text,
                width: this.getProperty("buttonWidth"),
                height: this.getProperty("buttonHeight"),
                press: function (oEvent) {
                    oControl.fireClick({
                        buttonValue : buttonValue
                    });
                }
            }).addStyleClass("virtualKeyboardButton " + styleClassName);
            return oBtn;
        },

        disableButton : function (buttonName) 
        { 
            // this.getAggregation(<any button aggregation>) returns "null"
            // this.getAggregation("_layout") returns the MatrixLayout-Aggregation
            this.getAggregation(buttonName).setEnabled(false);
        },

        renderer : {

            render : function(oRm, oControl) {                  

                oRm.write("<div");
                oRm.writeControlData(oControl);
                oRm.addStyle("width", oControl.getWidth());
                oRm.addStyle("margin-left", "44px");
                oRm.writeStyles();
                oRm.write(">");

                oRm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("_layout"));

                oRm.write("</div>");
            }
        }
    });


    de.vw.timerec.controls.VirtualKeyboard.prototype.exit = function () {

    };

}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a Button to the Aggregations in the MatrixLayout, they are automatically removed from your control's aggregations. Aggregation contents can only be in one aggregation at the same time. You will have to access them via ID. That's what UI5 Associations are for (they are basically groups that hold the IDs of the control instances).